# Parameter tuning Keras

Tags: python, performance, parameters, keras, deep-learning

First of all, I have to mention that I am totally newbie to Keras etc.

I have created the following keras model which after many errors works fine but I want to add parameter tuning.

My first question is, I have to transform the model like function if I want to add parameter tuning. Can someone give an example how to add parameter tuning for example, learning rate of the optimizer in a function format.. I get many error ...

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_idx + 1, word2vec.vector_size, 
input_length=MAX_SEQ_LEN))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Convolution1D(52, 5, padding='same',

kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(MaxPool1D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Convolution1D(128, 3, padding='same',

kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(MaxPool1D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(len(TARGET_CLASSES), activation='sigmoid',
            kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.02)))
model.compile(Adam(0.001), 'binary_crossentropy')
```

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried already, including full error messages and source code.